# How to post message with url on Facebook?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting a post on facebook. I am able to post a URL but I also want to post some description with that URL. I am using it -

```
NSString *shareUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%@&t=%@", urlString , description];
    NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString:urlString ];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

but I am not able to post description. So can you gave any idea to do this. I don't want to use any sdk or any api for to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API/tree/59e639922c4bf6953162ea81998f2ff951cd1769) as easy to use.

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];

[variables setObject:@"MESSAGE HERE" forKey:@"message"];
[variables setObject:@"URL HERE" forKey:@"link"];
[variables setObject:@"URL NAME HERE" forKey:@"name"];
[variables setObject:@"URL DESC HERE." forKey:@"description"];

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:variables];
```

Comment: Hello, When I click on postMeFeedButton then app is crashed but post is done. Can you tell me the reason of it?